# VS Code not highlighting python text

Tags: visual-studio-code

My vs code is not highlighting my python text. it does not color change the variables and imports etc. Only the strings and some other parts of the text.
I have python and pylint installed, I am also using the dark+ (default dark) as my color theme. I have also tried other options like the github dark theme, but same results. I am on windows 10.

[image]

any help

Comment: You can learn a lot from previous threads like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71519415/vs-code-pylance-not-highlighting-variables-and-modules

Comment: you have syntax highlighting, maybe your theme does not have colors defined for certain Textmate scopes, choose a different theme and see if that colors the uncolored

Comment: Thanks guys @LexLi installing pylance worked and restarting vscode worked

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently and I fixed it by removing an outdated python extention, it's name was 'Python for VSCode' by Thomas Haakon Townsend.

I hope this helped.

Comment: It was pylance all along. I had to install pylance and I got the text color back